# Forced NPM version in Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express, npm, versioning

We have a Nodejs + Express application and would like to force the application to successfully run `npm install` only if `npm -v` is equal to `process.env.npm_package_engines_npm`, which is the version of npm defined in package.json

Is this possible somehow?

The reason for this requirement is to be 100% sure all dependencies will be installed the same way in all development instances since recently we ran into some issues that some developers had version 5.2.0 and other 5.3.0 and because of this, the results were not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a js script file and run `node preinstall.js`

```
// preinstall.js
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('npm -v', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error + stderr);
    return;
  }

  const nodeVersion = stdout;

  if (process.env.npm_package_engines_npm === nodeVersion) {
    exec('npm install');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the [`engines` property in your package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines)

That will print out warnings if the npm version doesn't match what you have specified (this at least makes it clear to the user that they need to update npm even if it doesn't prevent the actual installation).

If you pass the [engine-strict](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#engine-strict) CLI flag then npm will error if the versions don't match:

```
$ npm install --engine-strict
```

Comment: I didn't know this one. Also very good as a secondary requirement to run `npm install`